# ERROR: TypeError: _co.keyupHandler is not a function in Angular 4 using tinymce

Tags: angular, tinymce

I followed this guide https://go.tinymce.com/blog/angular-2-and-tinymce/ and i got the editor working, but get this error when i type anything in the editor:

"TypeError: _co.keyupHandler is not a function".

If i comment out this part ..

```
    // editor.on('keyup change', () => {
    //   const content = editor.getContent();
    //   this.onEditorContentChange.emit(content);
    // });
```

.. then I dont get any error, but when submitting the form the description field is not updated. I have a feeling this is jquery code but how can I do it the angular way? Also not sure if formControlName is properly injected. It is applied to the app-tiny-editor, but should it be in the textarea? 
How it looks now:

[image]

Its all very confusing, hope someone can help.
Code:

wysiwyg component ts

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, AfterViewInit, EventEmitter, OnDestroy, Input, Output, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import 'tinymce';
import 'tinymce/themes/modern';
import 'tinymce/plugins/table';
import 'tinymce/plugins/link';
declare var tinymce: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tiny-editor',
  template: `<textarea name="{{elementId}}" id="{{elementId}}"></textarea>`,

})
export class TinyEditorComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() elementId: String;
  @Output() onEditorContentChange = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() value: any;
  @Input() fcn: any;
  @Input() control: FormControl;
  @ViewChild('textarea') inputRef: ElementRef;

editor: any;
  // editor;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    tinymce.init({
      init_instance_callback: (editor: any) => {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression
        editor && this.value && editor.setContent(this.value);
        },     
      selector: '#' + this.elementId,
      plugins: ['link', 'table'],
      skin_url: '/assets/skins/lightgray',
      setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup change', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.onEditorContentChange.emit(content);
        });
      }

    });
    console.log('control',this.control);

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    tinymce.remove(this.editor);
  }
}
```

in the component where im calling this:

```
   <app-tiny-editor [elementId]="'description'" name="description" 
        [control]="editEvent.controls['description']" 
        [fcn]="description" formControlName="description" 
        [value]="theevent.description"
          (onEditorContentChange)="keyupHandler($event)" ngDefaultControl>
          {{theevent.description}}
        </app-tiny-editor>
```